# Measuring TensorFlow Lite Model Speed

Tags: raspberry-pi, benchmarking, tensorflow-lite

### I measured the inference speed of each TensorFlow Lite Detection Model on a Raspberry Pi by following the instructions from the following link:

https://www.ejtech.io/learn/tflite-object-detection-model-comparison. On the website there is a series of commands to download and run the benchmark tool on the Pi:

### Commands to download and run TFLite benchmark tool

```
cd ~/tflite1
```

```
wget -O benchmark_model https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-nightly-public/prod/tensorflow/release/lite/tools/nightly/latest/linux_arm_benchmark_model_plus_flex
```

```
sudo chmod +x benchmark_model
```

```
./benchmark_model --graph=<graph_name>/detect.tflite --num_threads=4 --warmup_runs=10 --num_runs=100
```

### However, because my raspberry pi uses aarch64, I changed it to:

```
wget -O benchmark_model https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-nightly-public/prod/tensorflow/release/lite/tools/nightly/latest/linux_aarch64_benchmark_model_plus_flex
```

### I executed it on rasp terminal:

```
$ sudo chmod +x benchmark_model
```

```
$ ./benchmark_model --graph=Sample_TFLite_model/detect.tflite --num_threads=4 --warmup_runs=10 --num_runs=100
```

### The Result:

./benchmark_model: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.13` not found (required by ./benchmark_model)

./benchmark_model: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` not found (required by ./benchmark_model)

./benchmark_model: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34` not found (required by ./benchmark_model)

./benchmark_model: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32` not found (required by

./benchmark_model) ./benchmark_model: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33` not found (required by ./benchmark_model)

##### I'm stuck for 5 days here, maybe someone can help me :)